# Should I use post-hoc tukey HSD or some other test for pairwise comparisons of a factor on a zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model (ZINB)?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, zero-inflation, tukey-hsd-test

I ran a zero-inflated negative binomial mixed model (ZINB) and now have a statistically significant factor (recording type, either NOCA, BCCH, or Human).
To assess the differences between these three possibilities in the factor, could I rely on a post-hoc tukey HSD? Should I use the lsmeans tukey test in R? Would this post-hoc test be appropriate for assessing pairwise difference of a factor in a ZINB model given the random effects?

Also, would I be able to just run separate ZINB mixed models for each pairwise comparison on their own, or is that fundamentally incorrect? For example, run one model with a subset of the data that's just NOCA and BCCH, one model that's just BCCH and Human, and one that's just NOCA and Human?